# Linux error: -gt unary operator shell script

Tags: linux, while-loop, virtual-machine, command-prompt, operator-keyword

I am trying to make a custom command prompt. So for example if i type in . filename 1 hello 2 hi
The custom prompt should look like this: [][hello][hi][]$. Number 1 stands for second position and number 2 stands for the third position.
The code is not fully done, but when i'm trying to run it I get an error '-gt unary operator'

```
#!/bin/bash

$first $1 $second $2

PS1="[][][][]$"

while [ $first -gt -1 ] || [ $second -gt -1 ]

do
    if [ $first -eq 0 ]
    then
        PS1="[$1][][][]$"
    elif [ $first -eq 1 ]
    then
        PS1="[][$1][][]$"
    elif [ $first -eq 2 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][$1][]$"
    elif [ $first -eq 3 ]
    then
        PS1="[][][][$1]$"
    fi
done
```

I tried deleting the while loop to see if the same problem would occur for the if statements, and it did. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not assigned a value to '$first'.

So your while loop is essentially doing this:

```
[ -ge -1 ]
```

Which is invalid syntax and is what's causing your unary operator error.

The 2nd line of your script doesn't make sense.

```
$first $1 $second $2
```

In the case of the above arguments will try evaluate the following:
" 1  hello"

And you'll probably see an error like:

```
1: command not found
```

Comment: Never mind it solved the error! thanks for your help!